# Retrieve the index of an object stored in a collection using its key (VBA)

Tags: vba

I have a collection with several elements in VBA, and each of these elements has a key assigned.

I would like to know the position of a given element in the collection using its key. The only way I can think of doing this is to loop through the collection until I get the item I want. Is there a faster approach?

Thanks

Comment: Please could you share an example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Essentially, no. There's not a faster way. Not using a collection at least. Here's the fastest way I know to find the index of an item in a collection.

```
' returns index of item if found, returns 0 if not found
Public Function IndexOf(ByVal coll As Collection, ByVal item As Variant) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To coll.Count
        If coll(i) = item Then
            IndexOf = i
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Note that we exit the function as soon as we've found the first matching item. This algorithm has an average and worst case of **O(n)** where **n** is the number of items in the collection.

I think there may be another reason you want to be able to find the index though, so I'm going to suggest also taking a look at the [`Scripting.Dictionary`](http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Dictionary_en.html) in the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library. While, there is also no way to get an item's index via it's key value (other than looping), you **can** actually retrieve the key values from the dictionary, not just it's items. I suspect that you may be asking this question because of the lack of this ability in the built in `Collection` object.

Comment: This is a fine solution. Please note if you have objects stored, then VBA requires `is`, so the code line becomes `If coll(i) is item Then`.

Comment: Both solution and @peter_the_oak's comment are fine, thank you both. To add 0.02$, it is easily implemented as a:  `Select Case VarType(coll(i)) Case vbObject  If coll(i) Is item Then ... Case Else ... If coll(i) = item Then        ...`

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same "issue" and used this workaround:

Create two collections: one containing the actual strings of interest and one containing numbers from 1 to n with the actuals strings as keys. This way you can retrieve the index since it's a value in the second collection.

```
Sub example()

    'imagine we are reading out following excel column

    'one
    'two
    'three

    Dim textcol, numcol As New Collection
    Dim i, index As Integer
    Dim str As String

    For i = 1 To Range.Rows.Count
        textcol.Add Range.Cells(i, 1)       'value, no key
        numcol.Add i, Range.Cells(i, 1)     'i, value as key
    Next i

    'textcol: "one", "two", "three"
    'numcol: 1 ["one"], 2 ["two"], 3 ["three"]

    str = "two"
    index = numcol(str) '~> 2

End Sub
```

It's not pretty but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I liked Sil's answer above.  I think he short changed himself by saying 'Its not pretty but it works'.  In my experience it is way faster when doing a large number of lookups.
Here is another example

```
Sub UseCollectionWithKey()
Dim Col As New Collection
Dim I As Integer

' create a new collection that is keyed
For I = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Styles.Count
  Col.Add I, ActiveWorkbook.Styles(I)   ' where "ActiveWorkbook.Styles(I)" is the key
Next I

MsgBox Col(ActiveCell.Style)    ' this gives the index of the style for the active cell

End Sub
```

See also "Adding Items Using a Key" at this link
https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-collections/

Comment: Is this an answer?

Comment: @vega Yes it answers the original question (I would like to know the position of a given element in the collection using its key.) by giving an example where the position of an element can be retrieved using a key without looping through the collection each time.  I am new to posting on this forum so I would appreciate any feed back.

Comment: Are you sure this works? I get a type mismatch error with an Integer type as the Item.

Answer (score -2):

There is no way that I have found to return the index, however if you have a collection of user defined objects that will only be stored in a single collection you can add an index property to the object and set it when the object is added to the collection.