# How to get object's position within Collection?

Tags: excel, vba, class, collections

### Prerequisites:

I've got:

- a `Collection` called *"`users`"*
- which consits of instances of a `Class` called *"`MatchClass`"*
- the *"`MatchClass`"* consists of only two properties - `userid` and `matchArray` *(plus some methods which are not relevant to the question)*

---

### What I want to do

Is to **loop over the `Collection`**, while simultaneously being able to

- access the position within the collection
- access the properties of the class instance
- find the highest value out of all `matchArray`s *(they are already sorted)* and store the `userid`

---

### What I've tried so far:

To loop over the `Collection` with a `For Each` loop

> ```
> Dim users as New Collection
> Dim i as Byte
> Dim max as Integer: max = 0
> Dim maxuser as String
> ' users Collection is  filled with instances of MatchClass 
> ' ... skipping code to simplify ...
> Dim user as MatchClass
> For Each user in users
>         temp = user.matchArray(0, 0)
>         If temp > max Then
>             max = temp
>             maxuser = users.Item ' <- this won't work
>         End If
> Next user
> ```
>
> Then I can't acess the position of the `user` within the `For Each` loop

Alternatively I tried numerical looping:

> ```
> For i = users.Count to 1 Step -1
>    users.Item(i).matchArray(0, 0) ' <- this won't work
> Next i
> ```
>
> This unfortunately won't work either, as I can't access the properties
>   of the `MatchClass` instances via the `users.Item(i)` code either.

---

Is there perhaps a best of both worlds solution where I can do both?
Feels like it should be somethign arbitrary that I'm just missing.

Comment: Is it possible that you want the index of a collection like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28986212/6600940)

Comment: A simple way would be to include an index in your For Each loop and increment it by 1 each time you loop around. I could be wrong but I’m sure you can do what you’re wanting in a For loop though. Simply cast the item (users.Item(i)) to a MatchClass variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, I would've expected either of these methods to work.  Happy to be proven wrong though because they are untested ...

> For Each

```
Dim users As New Collection
Dim i As Byte
Dim max As Integer: max = 0
Dim maxuser As String
' users Collection is  filled with instances of MatchClass
' ... skipping code to simplify ...
Dim user As MatchClass

Dim lngIndex As Long

For Each user In users
        lngIndex = lngIndex + 1            
        temp = user.matchArray(0, 0)

        If temp > max Then
            max = temp
            maxuser = lngIndex
        End If
Next user
```

> For

```
Dim user As MatchClass

For i = users.Count To 1 Step -1
   Set user = users.item(i)
   matchArray = item.matchArray(0, 0)
Next i
```

If I've understood your question then I would’ve thought either of the above (if not both) would get you your desired result.

Comment: Oh yeah lol, that went completely over my head. Sometimes we attempt to find the most elegant and intricate of solutions, meanwhile we forget about the most basic ones.

Comment: @Rawrplus yes we do. The wife constantly tells me I overthink things.

Answer (score 1):

- If `MatchClass` is an object and `users` is a collection of `MatchClass` instances, then you should use `Set` keyword to assign an object reference (I'm referring to this line `maxuser = users.Item ' <- this won't work` -- but there is another problem with this line (mentioned below)).
- When you loop through a collection (in VBA), you are looping through its items. You do not have "read" access to its keys. So `Dim maxuser as String` doesn't make sense, unless you have a collection of strings, which you don't.
- The `Item` member of the `Collection` object requires either an index or the key that was originally used to add the item to the collection.

I cannot test this (so I might be wrong myself), but my view is:

```
Private Sub FindMaxUser()
    Dim users As New Collection

    Dim i As Byte
    Dim max As Long: max = 0

    Dim temp As Long
    ' ... skipping code to simplify ...

    Dim user As MatchClass
    Dim maxuser As MatchClass ' <- Shouldn't be a string.

    For Each user In users
        temp = user.matchArray(0, 0)
        If temp > max Then
            max = temp
            Set maxuser = user ' <- MatchClass is an object. "Set" keyword is required for object references
        End If

    Next user
End Sub
```

Key changes here are to declare `maxuser` as `MatchClass` and using `Set` inside the loop (when a new maximum value is found).

Comment: Technically this doesn't answer my question, because I was looking for the index of the "user" MatchClass within the Collection, but I upvoted nontheless, because it made a lot more sense to refer to the `maxuser` as an instance of `MatchClass` rather than a `String` - I basically combined your answer with @Skin